# Http-Server weird behavior with .js files

Tags: javascript, html, path, httpserver

I have a super basic website, which has an index.html, and 2 folders, js and css.[image]

app.js only contains a console.log, to show if the file is being loaded properly. If i open the index.html file by double clicking it, the messagge appears in chrome console normaly, when adding it to the html with this line:

[image]

However, if I open the webpage by executing http-server -o, that console.log is not printed in screen. In order to make it appear, I have to include script like this:

[image]

Can anyone explain why this happens? It just doesn´t make sense to me, but obviously there is an explanation.

Thank you

Comment: "_Http-Server_" is specifically [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)?

Comment: What kind of server is it?

Comment: It does not make sense and I can't reproduce it on my end so you must have missed something. Try using absolute paths.

Comment: @Teemu yes, that´s right.

Comment: Try using express and/or absolute path, or both, this is very odd

Comment: Isn't JS in a `link` tag not actually *run* at the time it loads? It's waiting for something within the file to be called, like `window.onload()`. But then in the `script` tag, it's running everything in it because it's essentially calling it once it loads?

Comment: I suppose there's Node.js running behind Https-server, probably node has a fixed router, which fetches all js files from a certain folder. When you open index from the filesystem, the file is run with file protocol, it's not run by Http-server, and the relative paths are correct. When you run the page with http protocol, the server is providing it, and the configured routes are used. Someone knowing Http-server could give a more accurate answer. Unfortunately Http-server tag doesn't exist, the current [httpserver] is more generic, it's not specified to Http-server.